# how to pass generator as parameters through functions

Tags: python, generator

I have this function

```
def build_permutations(positions, start, end):
    my_range = range(start,end+1) 
    permutations = (
        perm
        for perm in itertools.product(my_range, repeat=len(positions))
        if (sum(perm) / len(positions) <= end * .66) or sum(perm)/len(positions) >= (end * .1)
    )
    return permutations
```

which is returned in main here

```
    permutations = build_permutations(positions, args.sl, args.el)
    print(f"| Number of permutations: {sum(1 for _ in permutations)} | Runtime: {time.time() - permutation_time:.2f} seconds")
```

when I work with the generator returned here, it works well. I've tried printing all values in the generator in the print expression and that works. However

when I pass this generator through to the next function

```
    list_of_best_permutations = processing_technique(df,permutations, positions, sorted_map_of_positions,args.s)
```

and try to iterate through it like so

```
def processing_technique(df,permutations, positions, sorted_map_of_positions, starting_balance):

    df_rows = len(df.index)
    print((perm for perm in permutations))
```

or like so

```
def processing_technique(df,permutations, positions, sorted_map_of_positions, starting_balance):

    df_rows = len(df.index)
    for perm in permutations:
        print(perm)
```

it just breaks out and throws an index error way later in the code without printing anything

Comment: Generators are not reentrant in general, unless you make your custom generators/iterators that are. So once you consumed it to print the amount of items, you cannot expect that generator to yield same values again. Consider using `itertools.tee` (not helpful here - you'll end up effectively storing all items in memory), recreating the generator after consumption, memoizing directly (collect into `list` and reuse freely), or refactoring your code to avoid double iteration.

Comment: haha that's hilarious, so much time wasted. Should I delete the question or?

Comment: Nope, the question is at least well written, let's search for dupes, if there are some - close as duplicate, if no - I'll write an answer here shortly. Generators are closer to quantum physics: your observation actually changed what goes on:)

Comment: haha, so if it takes a long time to create the generator, is there no way to avoid that repeated work besides storing it in memory?

Comment: In the specific case you show, **creating** a generator takes almost zero time. All time is spent during actual iteration (creating next values), and so only removing second iteration round (or first - just count/enumerate and print the total length afterwards, you can even encapsulate this logic into generator itself by replacing generator expr with plain old `yield`) could prevent both having big memory footprint and spending time on new values generation.